# Odd For Loop Behavior with String Array

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, debugging, for-loop

I have the following code that dimensions and fills a 26-length String Array:

```
    Dim intAllWeights As Integer = intFrontWeights + intKingpinWeights + 
    intLandingLegWeights + intCenterWeights + intBogieWeights + intRearWeights
    Dim AllWeightsString(intAllWeights - 1) As String
    Dim k As Integer = 1
    For j = 1 To intFrontWeights
        AllWeightsString(k - 1) = ("F - " + strFrontWeightDescription(j - 1) + ": " + "(x" + intFrontWeightQuantity(j - 1).ToString + "), " + dblFrontWeightWeight(j - 1).ToString + Pounds + ", " + dblFrontWeightOffset(j - 1).ToString + Inches)
        k = k + 1
    Next
    For j = 1 To intKingpinWeights
        AllWeightsString(k - 1) = ("K - " + strKingpinWeightDescription(j - 1) + ": " + "(x" + intKingpinWeightQuantity(j - 1).ToString + "), " + dblKingpinWeightWeight(j - 1).ToString + Pounds + ", " + dblKingpinWeightOffset(j - 1).ToString + Inches)
        k = k + 1
    Next
    For j = 1 To intLandingLegWeights
        AllWeightsString(k - 1) = ("L - " + strLandingLegWeightDescription(j - 1) + ": " + "(x" + intLandingLegWeightQuantity(j - 1).ToString + "), " + dblLandingLegWeightWeight(j - 1).ToString + Pounds + ", " + dblLandingLegWeightOffset(j - 1).ToString + Inches)
        k = k + 1
    Next
    For j = 1 To intCenterWeights
        AllWeightsString(k - 1) = ("C - " + strCenterWeightDescription(j - 1) + ": " + "(x" + intCenterWeightQuantity(j - 1).ToString + "), " + dblCenterWeightWeight(j - 1).ToString + Pounds + ", " + dblCenterWeightOffset(j - 1).ToString + Inches)
        k = k + 1
    Next
    For j = 1 To intBogieWeights
        AllWeightsString(k - 1) = ("B - " + strBogieWeightDescription(j - 1) + ": " + "(x" + intBogieWeightQuantity(j - 1).ToString + "), " + dblBogieWeightWeight(j - 1).ToString + Pounds + ", " + dblBogieWeightOffset(j - 1).ToString + Inches)
        k = k + 1
    Next
    For j = 1 To intRearWeights
        AllWeightsString(k - 1) = ("R - " + strRearWeightDescription(j - 1) + ": " + "(x" + intRearWeightQuantity(j - 1).ToString + "), " + dblRearWeightWeight(j - 1).ToString + Pounds + ", " + dblRearWeightOffset(j - 1).ToString + Inches)
        k = k + 1
    Next
```

When I step through the code line-by-line, I get this result:
[image]

When I break out after this code has ran without going line-by-line, I get this:
[image]

As you can see, the 25th index does not get set equal to anything if I do not F8-step through my code. Any ideas why this is happening? Very confused.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce this code considerably:

```
Dim buildStrings As Func(Of String, String(), Integer(), Double(), Double(), IEnumerable(Of String)) = _ 
    Function(Prefix, Description, Quantity, Weight, Offset)
        Dim Length As Integer = Description.Length
        Return Enumerable.Range(0, Length).Select(Function(j) _
            String.Format("{0} - {1}:(x{2}), {3}{4}, {5}{6}",
               Prefix, Description(j), Quantity(j), Weight(j), Pounds, Offset(j), Inches))
    End Function

Dim FrontStrings   = buildStrings("F", strFrontWeightDescription,      intFrontWeightQuantity,      dblFrontWeightWeight,      dblFrontWeightOffset)
Dim KingpinStrings = buildStrings("K", strKingpinWeightDescription,    intKingpinWeightQuantity,    dblKingpinWeightWeight,    dblKingpinWeightOffset)
Dim LandingStrings = buildStrings("L", strLandingLegWeightDescription, intLandingLegWeightQuantity, dblLandingLegWeightWeight, dblLandingLegWeightOffset)
Dim CenterStrings  = buildStrings("C", strCenterWeightDescription,     intCenterWeightQuantity,     dblCenterWeightWeight,     dblCenterWeightOffset)
Dim BogieStrings   = buildStrings("B", strBogieWeightDescription,      intBogieWeightQuantity,      dblBogieWeightWeight,      dblBogieWeightOffset)
Dim RearStrings    = buildStrings("R", strRearWeightDescription,       intRearWeightQuantity,       dblRearWeightWeight,       dblRearWeightOffset)

Dim AllWeightsString = FrontStrings.Concat(KingpinStrings).Concat(LandingStrings).Concat(CenterStrings).Concat(BogieStrings).Concat(RearStrings).
                         ToArray()
```

This may seem more complicated at first, especially if the anonymous functions and linq features are unfamiliar, but by reducing the repetition and total code, it's actually easier to understand in the long rung.

You can make this even better and far less complicated by using `Class`es for this, instead of grouped arrays. Using arrays to match up data by index is an anti-pattern that should be avoided. Here is what a class might look like:

```
Public Enum WeightType
    Front
    Kingpin
    LandingLeg
    Center
    Bogie
    Rear
End Enum

Public Class WeightInfo
    Const Pounds As String = "[lbs.]"
    Const Inches As String = "[in]"

    Public Property Style As WeightType
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Quantity As Integer
    Public Property Weight As Double
    Public Property Offset As Double

    Public ReadOnly Property StylePrefix As String
        Get
            Select Case Style
                Case WeightType.Front
                    Return "F"
                Case WeightType.Kingpin
                    Return "K"
                Case WeightType.LandingLeg
                    Return "L"
                Case WeightType.Center
                    Return "C"
                Case WeightType.Bogie
                    Return "B"
                Case WeightType.Rear
                    Return "R"
                Case Else
                    Return ""
            End Select
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} - {1}:(x{2}), {3}{4}, {5}{6}", StylePrefix, Description, Quantity, Weight, Pounds, Offset, Inches)
    End Function
End Class
```

If your data is set up in arrays of class instances, then the code becomes something more like this:

```
Dim AllWeightsString = _ 
       FrontWeights.Select(Function(w) w.ToString).Concat(
       KingpinWeights.Select(Function(w) w.ToString)).Concat(
       LandingLegWeights.Select(Function(w) w.ToString)).Concat(
       CenterWeights.Select(Function(w) w.ToString)).Concat(
       BogieWeights.Select(Function(w) w.ToString)).Concat(
       RearWeights.Select(Function(w) w.ToString)).
       ToArray()
```

Semantically, that's only one line of code. And you can get better still by putting all your data in **ONE** big collection (*not* array) that you can filter using a `Where()` by type as needed. For example:

```
Dim FrontWeights = AllMyWeights.Where(Function(w) w.Style = WeightType.Front)
```

Comment: I run this code and AllWeightsString is Nothing. Also, for my intent, I need an array of strings.

Comment: This will produce an array of strings, though I suspect you could really get by with IEnumerable(Of String) and it would perform much better. Make sure you run past the last line. AllWeightsString isn't assigned until after that line is finished. If you're stopped there on a breakpoint you won't see anything. Oh... are you possibly re-defining a class member variable inside a method?

Comment: A Class member is not being redefined. I still cannot wrap my head around on why the String Array is created properly only when I step through the code... obviously the end-user will not have that ability.

Comment: The code you posted works, I will mark as Correct. Thank you. I am a mechanical engineer by education writing this program without a SE's level of knowledge when it comes to this stuff.. could you explain why this was happening?

Comment: My suspicion (can't confirm without seeing ALL of the original code) was the break point was happening in a different place than you expected.

Comment: Could you explain how the function buildStrings() is able to iterate through my arrays that hold the info for each weight type?

Comment: Enumerable.Range generates an index for each array cell, then Select call uses those indexes to translate the array values into the string